# Realm object notifications from nested objects

Tags: swift, realm

I have an app where I want to get notified when a property of a certain Realm Object changes. It works fine for basic properties.

But my object also contains another Realm object inside and I only get notifications when that object is added or removed to the parent object.

If a property of the nested object changes I do not get notified.

Is there any way to get notified when properties in the nested object changes?

Comment: Can you share your models and the code around registering notification? Realm's collection notification should notify not only when added or deleted relationships, but also when changed.

Comment: @kishikawakatsumi what do you mean by `changed`? are you meaning the property of that nested object changed or the nested property changed (assigned new nested object)?

Answer (score 0):

I think the key here is to use a [collection notification](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#collection-notifications) limited by that object's `primaryKey`, and then you will receive a notification for changes in the nested object's properties.